# D3 won't append elements after external JSON is loaded

Tags: d3.js

So I've been trying to get my head around this, but somehow D3 won't append the `g` element to the SVG.

I created a function totalpoints and called it after the element I want it to add the SVG to. This all works fine, but it won't append any element to the SVG..

```
var chart = d3.select(id)
        .append("svg") //append svg element inside #chart
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right) //set width
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom); //set height

    d3.json("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com//s/339pul17xrdsk6w/data.json?raw=1", function(error, data) {

        var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
            .append("g") //append svg element inside #chart
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);
    });
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dmL2n54j/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was simple. The original JSON was

```
{"section":"Totale punten voor","points":"1791"}
```

What worked was putting `[]` around it, like

```
[{"section":"Totale punten voor","points":"1791"}]
```

The `g` element appears.

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) two problems:

**No Data**

In your `d3.json`, you're not using the loaded `data` anywhere.

You should have something like:

```
var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    ...
```

`d3` works by matching visual elements with data for display, and from its point of view, you did not give it any.

**Only Group Elements**

The only added elements are css groups. They, by themselves, do not display anything.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far, but it won't still append after your suggestions. See my altered [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dmL2n54j/2/). Any ideas?

Comment: When I inspect in the HTML window the SVG is empty and the `g` element is nowhere to be seen. The JSON file has only 1 entry, has it got something to do with that?

Comment: I'll have to continue this much later. Sorry.